# How to embed if statement inside echo

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

I'm gettin' a headache on that. I need to put if statement inside an echo (this echo is in a function, it's for a form submit actually)

Here is an example on a partial of my code. In this situation, how can I put theses if statement inside my echo??

```
   <?php echo '<td><select id="depuis" name="depuis">
    <option value=\'4\' <?php if(isset($_POST[\'depuis\']) && $_POST[\'depuis\'] == \'4\'){ echo \'selected\'; } else { echo ''; } ?> ></option>
    <option value=\'1\' <?php if(isset($_POST[\'depuis\']) && $_POST[\'depuis\'] == \'1\'){ echo \'selected\'; } else { echo ''; } ?> >2 ans et moins</option>
    <option value=\'2\' <?php if(isset($_POST[\'depuis\']) && $_POST[\'depuis\'] == \'2\'){ echo \'selected\'; } else { echo ''; } ?> >2 &agrave; 5 ans</option>
    <option value=\'3\' <?php if(isset($_POST[\'depuis\']) && $_POST[\'depuis\'] == \'3\'){ echo \'selected\'; } else { echo ''; } ?> >5 ans et plus</option>
</select>
</td>'
; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is php so need to use more than the first `<?php` Finish each `echo` before checking with `if`. Like this:

```
<?php 
  echo '<td><select id="depuis" name="depuis">
    <option value="4"'; 
    if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && $_POST['depuis'] == '4') { 
      echo ' selected'; 
    } 
 echo ' >Something here maybe?</option>...etc
```

Comment: Great! This is quite simple, no need of new variables, +1 !

Answer (score 5):

Use an inline if statement:

```
echo 'Based on your score, you are a ',($score > 10 ? 'genius' : 'nobody');
```

Comment: @machineaddict - `echo` can take a comma separated list of arguments, as well as a string.

Comment: @andrewsi: Thanks for the info. I just tested it and it works. Sorry Aidan.

Comment: @machineaddict: No worries

Comment: Works perfect, I love it

Answer (score 3):

This would work - although I'm sure it could be streamlined:

```
<?php

$out = '
    <td>
        <select id="depuis" name="depuis">
        <option value="4"
    ';

    if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && $_POST['depuis'] == '4'){ 
        $out .= 'selected';
    } 

    $out .= '
        ></option>
        <option value='1' 
    ';

    if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && $_POST['depuis'] == '1'){ 
        $out .= 'selected';
    }

    $out .= '
        >2 ans et moins</option>
        <option value=\'2\' 
    ';


    if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && $_POST['depuis'] == '2'){ 
        $out .= 'selected';
    }

    $out .= '
        >2 &agrave; 5 ans</option>
        <option value='3' 
    ';

    if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && $_POST['depuis'] == '3'){ 
        $out .= 'selected';
    }

    $out .= '
            >5 ans et plus</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    ';

    echo $out;
?>
```

Meilleurs voeux...

Comment: Merci beaucoup, a toi aussi! :)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the a ternary operator which acts as a shortened IF/Else statement:

`echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.(($value=='United States')?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$value.'</option>';`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't escape the array keys in the string

```
if(isset($_POST[\'depuis\']) ...
```

Should be

```
if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && ...
```

Also you could clean up the the generation of the options with a array and a loop

```
$options = array(
  'label1' => 1,
  'label2' => 2,
  'label3' => 3,
  'label4' => 4
);
$value = (isset($_POST['depuis'])) ? $_POST['depuis'] : 0;

foreach ($options as $label => $optionValue) {
  $selected = ($optionValue == $value) ? ' selected' : '';

  printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $optionValue, $selected, $label); 
}
```

Comment: If the order is important, you might say `foreach (['4', '1', '2', '3'] as $x)`.

Comment: (BTW, all your options have `value="4"`.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do that like you're asking.  You'd just need to use regular if/else if block and output the outcome separately.

```
<?php 
echo("<td><select id=\"depuis\" name=\"depuis\">");
echo("<option value='4'");
if(isset($_POST['depuis']) && $_POST['depuis'] == '4'){ echo("selected"); } 
echo("></option>");

[ ...etc... ]
?>
```