# If and else statement in PHP inside of an echo

Tags: php, html

I want to give the admin the ability to activate the user account so I have to status active and inactive
When I run my code I get 4 status
Active 
Inactive 
Active 
Inactive 
You will find here a screenshot to understand the problem I’m facing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBNOQ.png

```
    if(isset($_GET['id_user'])){

        include("conexion.php");

        $rep=$db->query("select * from user WHERE id_user=" .$_GET['id_user']  );

        while($l=$rep->fetch()){
echo "

<form class= mainSettingsForm add method='POST'>


    <label>Numero utlisateur :</label>
    <input disabled='disabled' type='text' name='ref' value=' ".$l[0]." ' ></input> 
    <input name='id_user2' type='hidden' value='".$l[0]."' ></input> 

    <label>Nom utlisateur :  </label>    
    <input type='text' name='username2' value='".$l[1]."' > 

    <label> nom :    </label>   
    <input type='text' name='nom2' value='".$l[3]."' > 

    <label> prenom :      </label>
    <input type='text' name='prenom2' value='".$l[4]."' > 

    <label> Statut :  </label>    
    <select name=statut >


      if ($l[6] ==active) {
      echo '
      <option value=active >active</option>
      <option value=inactive >inactive</option>  }'

      else {
      echo '
      <option value=inactive >inactive</option>      
      <option value=active >active</option> }'

        </select>



   <input class=btn-primary type='submit' name='enregistrer' value='enregistrer' > 

    </form>"; // fin echo
    }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: close echo, run if, open echo. Learning the very basics of the language  syntax  would help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if block inside echo statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507042/if-block-inside-echo-statement) or [How to embed if statement inside echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175753/how-to-embed-if-statement-inside-echo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may not have been properly formed. Try this instead:

```
    <?php

        if( isset($_GET['id_user']) ){              
            include("conexion.php");                
            $rep = $db->query( "select * from user WHERE id_user=" . $_GET['id_user']  );

            // YOU ARE FETCHING A SINGLE USER... NO NEED FOR A LOOP...
            // JUST GET THE ARRAY OBJECT AND USE IT DIRECTLY...
            $l  = $rep->fetch();
    ?>

    <form class= mainSettingsForm add method='POST'>            
        <label>Numero utlisateur :</label>
        <input disabled='disabled' type='text' name='ref' value='<?php echo $l[0]; ?>'/>
        <input  name='id_user2' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $l[0]; ?>'/>

        <label>Nom utlisateur :</label>
        <input type='text' name='username2' value='<?php echo $l[1]; ?>' />

        <label>Nom :</label>
        <input type='text' name='nom2' value='<?php echo $l[3]; ?>' />

        <label>Prenom :</label>
        <input type='text' name='prenom2' value='<?php echo $l[4]; ?>' />

        <label>Statut :</label>         
        <select name=statut >               
            <option value='active' <?php if($l[6] == "active"){ echo "selected";} ?> >active</option>
            <option value='inactive' <?php if($l[6] == "inactive"){ echo "selected";} ?>inactive</option>
        </select>           

        <input class=btn-primary type='submit' name='enregistrer' value='enregistrer' >     
    </form>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I’m still getting active as a first choice even if the status of the user is inactive! Regards.

Comment: @AbdelhakOhammou    What is the content of $l[6]? Can you do a var_dump($l[6])? This will tell you if $l[6] contains the String "active" or "inactive". Let me know what you find then. Cheers...

Comment: I fixed the problem, thank you for your time, I really appreciate.